# websphere queue connection factory - Test connection - not working set up issues

Tags: java, ibm-mq, websphere-7

I tried setting up a websphere queue connection factory however get the following error:

> A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following
>   reason: CC=2;RC=2009

Any ideas?
This is what I did:

1. Installed websphere 7.0 base version
2. Installed update installer
3. installed fix pack 27 (7.0.0.27)
4. installed websphere MQ Explorer and able to browse the remote queue
5. Configure the queue connection factories >> resources >> JMS >> Queue connection factories >> cell scope >> new >> websphere MQ Queue messaging provider >> Name : test >> Jndi Name: jndi/test  >> Description : Test queue connection factory >> Enter all the required information to wizard >> Queue Manager NAme : SMSD1 >> Transport : Client >> Hostname : SMSMQD1 >> port : 1414 >> Server connection Channel : SMS1.SVRCONN >> Test connection : A connection could not be made to WebSphere MQ for the following reason: CC=2;RC=2009

Comment: what is your WAS MQ version? It looks like this issue was fixed in 7.0.1.6: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV00348

Comment: IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer

Version: 7.5.0.0

Comment: Do you have a listener started?

Comment: This issue is resolved by running a jython script

Comment: ras = AdminUtilities.convertToList(AdminConfig.list('J2CResourceAdapter'))
for ra in ras :
   desc = AdminConfig.showAttribute(ra, "description")
   if ((desc == "WAS 7.0 Built In WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter") or (desc == "WAS 7.0.0.1 Built In WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter")):
      print "Updating archivePath and classpath of " + ra
      AdminConfig.modify(ra, [['archivePath', "${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar"]])
      AdminConfig.unsetAttributes(ra, ['classpath'])
      AdminConfig.modify(ra, [['classpath',

Comment: "${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar"]])
      AdminConfig.save()
   #end if
#end for